# Calling a JavaScript function from jQuery returns ReferenceError: method not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var MyObj = core.Class.extend({

    connect: function() {
     $('body').keydown(function (e) {
        // want to call disconnect() in here
     });
    },

    disconnect: function() {
    }

});
```

I've tried calling `disconnect()`, `this.disconnect()`, but they all return,

> ReferenceError: disconnect is not defined

The variable `core` here is:

```
core = require('some_module')
```

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript syntax. A colon, closing parenthesis and comma are missing. Please check your code before posting.

Comment: @trincot sorry it was a type. fixed.

Comment: You only fixed one of three errors. Please check before posting that your code actually compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the `this` context into a variable.

Your code is using `this` context of this function: `$('body').keydown(function (e) {...}`

```
var MyObj = core.Class.extend({

  connect: function() {
    var $self = this;
    $('body').keydown(function(e) {
      $self.disconnect();
    });
  },

  disconnect: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` is not the right `this`.

Use this :

```
 $('body').keydown((e)=>{
        // this.disconnect() in here
     })
```

instead

Lambda functuons keep the context on which they run.

You can also use bind function and also keep a variable which keeps the context and then refer to that variable

Comment: Or if he doesn't want to go ES6 `$('body').keydown(function (e) {
        this.disconnect() }.bind(this))`. Also your answer lacks any sort of information as of why your code fixes the problem.

Comment: Edited with explanation